# autosizing movieclips to match text size (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, text, dynamic, border, autosize

I'm looking to add a specialized border around some dynamic text.
A special type of border that filters just can not produce

So I need this border to match the length of the dynamic text.
Unfortunately this code is not working

```
thistext.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
border.width = thistext.width;
```

What happens is, the border width is set to the initial starting width of the text and is not changed as the width of the text changes

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather listen only to text changes : `flash.events.Event.CHANGE`, instead of checking every frame.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:change

Besides, you may use textWidth attribute to get actual text width,  no matter the  value of autosize attribute (Width must be set to the maximum width). I'm not a huge fan of auto size feature which hides the maximum width, although it exists internally ( equal to the width attribute of the textfield, BEFORE setting autosize..). I'd rather have a less "magical" but more clear behavior, but it's debatable, especially if your text has to interact with the mouse (click,hover..), then you can take advantage of the bounds being automatically updated

Answer (score 0):

I actually caught my mistake. 
I need to add the code into an event listener that checks every frame AFTER the dynamic change so this code works

```
border.width = thistext.width;
```